# How do I stop unwanted text from appearing when I write multi-line comments in Sublime Text (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, multiline

In Ruby multi-line comments are written with `=begin` and `=end`.

When I type `=begin`, default text pops up after what I wrote regarding an error. Sublime Version 3.2.1. The automatic text that pops up is

> rescue Exception => e

referring to an exception in Ruby. I am looking to stop this text from appearing every time I create a multi-line comment.

I have tried looking at the Sublime Text Preferences (version 3) and google searching for related questions, and I have reviewed Sublime documentation but I have not found anything that will help. There is a file for Ruby preferences on sublime text, but mine is empty so I am not sure what to add.

```
=begin

rescue Exception => e

=end
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is that the `Ruby` package that ships with Sublime includes a series of snippets and one of them inserts a `begin-rescue-end` block in response to the text `begin` followed by the autocomplete completion key. There are a couple of ways to stop this from happening that involve changing how the snippet is triggered or what the snippet contains.

First, you can tweak the setting of `auto_complete_commit_on_tab`:

```
    // By default, auto complete will commit the current completion on enter.
    // This setting can be used to make it complete on tab instead.
    // Completing on tab is generally a superior option, as it removes
    // ambiguity between committing the completion and inserting a newline.
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false,
```

As the comment describes, this setting controls whether <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> is used to select an autocomplete entry from the popup, with the default being <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

From your problem description, you may be running with this setting set at the default; thus whenever you type `begin` the autocomplete entry for the snippet appears in the list, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> selects the item and expands it.

If that's the case, then flipping the value of the setting to `true` will stop this from happening; when you type `begin` the popup will still offer the snippet, but when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will be interpreted as a "normal" enter, and the snippet won't expand.

This also has the benefit that you can still utilize the snippet for it's intended purpose outside of comments to quickly set up a rescue block. Note however that if you make use of the autocomplete popup in other cases, this would require you to train your brain that you need to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> where you used to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can disable the snippet or alter what it inserts to make your life a little better. To do that, you would select `Preferences: Browse Packages` from the command palette or the main menu to open the `Packages` folder.

Inside of that folder, create a folder named `Ruby`, and then inside of that folder create a folder named `Snippets`, and inside of that folder a file named `Wrap-in-Begin-Rescue-End.sublime-snippet` (the case is important; the names should be exact for all of the files and folders here).

If you create an empty file when you do this, then the snippet in the `Ruby` package will be complete disabled and can no longer be triggered.

Alternately, you can instead give the file you create content that looks something like this:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
begin
    $0
=end
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>begin</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.ruby - comment</scope>
    <description>complete block comment</description>
</snippet>
```

That will make the text `begin` expand out to be the text in the snippet content area, which will add the text `begin` followed by the close of the block comment, and leave the cursor in the middle where the `$0` is located.

You can alter that as needed, such as altering the indent or changing where the cursor is placed, etc.

Comment: I used the option to disable the particular snippet. This works perfectly. thank you!